# How can I have phpstan find my custom extension class?

Tags: php, static-analysis, phpstan

To implement checks for some magic `_get()` functions, I'm trying to implement a "class reflection extension". [The manual](https://phpstan.org/developing-extensions/class-reflection-extensions) mentions how to write the extension files themselves, and to install them by adding a `service` part to the neon file.

I've written an extension, and added it like so:

```
services:
    -
        class: TestClass
        tags:
            - phpstan.broker.methodsClassReflectionExtension
```

This results in the following error:

> Service '0226': Class TestClass not found.

Things I've tried:

- using the standalone phar
- using the composer install of phpstan
- using a specific namespace (PHPStan) for the extension (in the file and in the neon)
- using a "random" namespace (in the file and in the neon)
- Adding the file to a directory I know is being scanned for analysis
- Adding the directory with the extension to the "scanDirectories" parameter
- Adding the file to the "scanFiles" parameter
- Adding the directory with the extension to the "paths" parameter
- Adding a (deprecated) autoload directive and adding the file there.

Several of these 'adding' tries actually warn if the file is not found: if, for instance, I make a deliberate typo in one of these, lets say the autoload one, it will warn me of a missing file. But only if I don't have the `service` defined.

If I have the service defined and the deliberate typo in there, it returns above class-not-found (and not the typo), so I feel it's checking the extension before any of the parameters?

There seems to be a need for adding my file to a different autoloading mechanism. The question is, which and how?

I'm using

- phpstan 0.12.40
- php 7.2.33

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension class needs to be loaded in runtime. You can achieve that in two ways:

1. Make the class available for the Composer autoloader. It's usually sufficient to configure [`autoload-dev`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev) section of your composer.json.
2. Create a file called something like `phpstan-autoload.php` in which you `require_once` the file with the extension class. And pass the path to the  `phpstan-autoload.php` file as [`--autoload-file|-a`](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/command-line-usage#--autoload-file%7C-a) option on the command line when running PHPStan.

Comment: P. S. Don't hesitate to ask the question on the GitHub PHPStan's issue tracker :) https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/new/choose

Comment: Ow! I avoided making an 'issue' to not put too much pressure on it, you're dealing with enough questions already so i hoped 'the community' could pick it up here ;) I'll head over there next time!